# How do I vertical-align text relative to a floated image?

Tags: css, css-float

There are a number of questions addressing this issue, but none addressing vertical alignment relative to a floated image or block-level element.

```
...
<td>
  <span style="vertical-align: middle">This should be vertically centered relative to the image</span>
  <img src="something" style="float: right" />
</td>
...
```

This does not produce the desired result, since the image is floating.  I have tried a lot of things, including adding a  after the  tag, making the span display as a block level element, and other ways to position the image (aligned to the right of the containing ) without floating it, but have not had success.

**UPDATE:**
I have been unable to get any of the proposed solutions working.  If this can't be done, so be it, but I'm leaving this open until I can be sure it can't.  I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigdave/G6JUs/) with the HTML, in hopes that someone can write CSS which demonstrates a solution.

Comment: Is the text long enough and/or the container small enough that the text will need to bump into the image and wrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be done without modifying the given document structure, at least given CSS2.1.  I'd still love to see a CSS3 solution, if anyone can provide one.

Answer (score 2):

```
...
<td>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>text here</td>
      <td style="text-align: right">image here</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
...
```

The <td> tag is align middle by default

Comment: Yeah that would be much simpler.  Just keep in mind you'd need to colspan the other cells above and below these.  Boy do I miss table driven design o,O

Comment: Your solution breaks the <td> into two.  This is an image dynamically inserted into the same <td> as the text.

Comment: Perhaps you could have a table in a td? I don't know how your dynamic insert code works, but it would be much simpler (and dependable) if you could use tables like shown. I updated my code.

Comment: Downvoted for suggesting using tables as part of layout. If you must, use `display:table-cell` with appropriate markup.

Comment: Unfortunately `table-cell` is not supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap the span and image in the same `<div>` and apply the float to the div instead.

```
...
<td>
  <div style="float: right;">
    <span style="vertical-align: middle">This should be vertically centered relative to the image</span>
    <img src="something" />
  </div>
</td>
...
```

OR

```
...
<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
  <span>This should be vertically centered relative to the image</span>
  <img src="something" style="float: right;" />
</td>
...
```

Comment: This would make the text float to the right also, correct?  The desired result is for the text to essentially be left-aligned, and the image right-aligned.

Comment: You could just keep what you have, and put the vertical-align: middle on your <td> instead. I updated my answer with this option under the OR.

Comment: You might also need to add a <br style="clear: both;" /> below the <img>.